# Query to roll up two records into one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't seem to figure this sql out. I'm thinking I may need some VBA but:

I have two tables related by ID where its a one to many relationship.

```
table1                     table2
ID                         ID, Date
```

Sample:

```
table1                     table2
1234                       1234, 12/31/2019
                           1234, 10/1/2021
```

The result I want back is **one** record with two columns:

```
ID              Date
1234            12/31/2019 | 10/1/2021
```

So I return one record with the two (or more) dates concatenated into one column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also study [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266386/concatrelated-in-complex-database-parsing-problems/57267201#57267201).

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT Table1.*
    , [MyDate] = Isnull( Stuff(
        (SELECT N' | ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), Table2.MyDate, 22), 11)) FROM Table2
        WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, N''), N'')
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Not for Access, it won't.

Comment: Oh, Access-only. Sorry, that's indeed Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server).